# getTop() is returning 2 for all views in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-view, tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` with views in the cells.  When one of the views is touched, I try to use `view.getTop()`.  The problem is that this is returning `2` whichever view I press. `getLeft()` works - it gives me correct values, but not `getTop()`.  `getBottom()` also behaves in a similar way, but returning `122` instead.

Comment: That it's normal, `getTop()` returns the position **relative to the parent** and in its parent the cells views start from the top of the `TableRow` widget(with 2 being a padding/margin most likely).

Comment: @Luksprog I have a a grid 6x6 as shown in the screenshots here http://stackoverflow.com/q/19604968/2442638.  So why does the `getLeft()` return a different value for each dot then? And is there a way to get the y values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that this is returning 2 whichever view I press.

The `getTop/Left/Right/Bottom()` methods are relative to the parent, this means that the values returned are relative to the parent bounds(which become the axes of the coordinates system for the child views). The cell view in a `TableLayout` has as parent a `TableRow`. The top side of that `TableRow` translates to a `0` y value returned by calling `getTop()` on one of the children. In your case this is 2 as you probably have a small margin/padding set on the cell view.

> So why does the getLeft() return a different value for each dot then?

There isn't something special about this. The left side of the `TableRow` translates to a x value of `0`, the next child will have a x value of 0 + the previous child's width and so on. For the height you don't get to see this because you only have one child in that direction.

Here's a small quote from the docs of the View class related to this methods:

*"It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. These methods both return the location of the view relative to its parent. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct parent."*

You could use one of the `getLocationInScreen/Window` methods or you could offset the `getTop()` value of the cell view with the `getTop()` value of the parent `TableRow` obtaining the x,y values relative to the `TableLayout` widget.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and the idea of offsetting the `getTop()` value.  What led me to asking this question was a result of a converstion with @blackbelt on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19615721/2442638 , where I was using the `getLocationInScreen` method, but the values were still wrong.

Comment: @RiThBo That method should work, but you could be facing device differences(especially if you say if on one device the values are correct).

Comment: I did some more testing, and that method does not work well on any device because when I change the padding or position of a layout, then the layout obviously moves, but the point where I press, and the coordinates I am trying to get don't match up.